# I Have Several Problems In Gson Library in (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Hello Stackoverflow community

I Would like to fetch data from this Rest Api:

https://adeega.xisaabso.online/Api/android_today_dashboard.php

but unfortunately i have several problems in my application

so how can i solved, i am new in jetpack compose

here are my problems:

1. No value passed for parameter 'Amaahda'
2. No value passed for parameter 'Expenses'
3. No value passed for parameter 'Lacagta_La_dirayo'
4. No value passed for parameter 'Total'
5. No value passed for parameter 'Amaahda'
6. None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

**build gradle**

```
implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

**DashBoardItems Class**

```
package com.example.eee.Classes

data class DashBoardItems(
    val Amaahda: Float,
    val Expenses: Float,
    val Lacagta_La_dirayo: Float,
    val Total: Float
)
```

**DashBoardScreen.kt**

```
package com.example.eee.Screens

import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.example.eee.Cards.DashBoardText
import com.example.eee.Classes.DashBoardItems
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder




@Composable
fun DashBoard_Screen(navController: NavController){

val context = LocalContext.current
val baseUrl = "https://adeega.xisaabso.online/Api/android_last_vouchers.php"

val dashBoardItems_data = DashBoardItems()

val data = remember {
    mutableStateOf<DashBoardItems>(DashBoardItems())
}

val stringRequest = StringRequest(baseUrl, { it ->
    val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
    val gson = gsonBuilder.create()
    gson.fromJson(it, DashBoardItems::class.java)
    data.value = dashBoardItems_data
}, {
    Toast.makeText(context, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}).apply {
    DashBoardText(data = data.value)
}

val volleyRequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
volleyRequest.add(stringRequest)

}
```

**DashBoardText Composable**

```
package com.example.eee.Cards

import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import com.example.eee.Classes.DashBoardItems


@Composable
fun DashBoardText(data: DashBoardItems){
    Text(text = data.Total.toString())
    Text(text = data.Amaahda.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those two places, you are calling `DashBoardItems` constructor without any argument, but it requires 4 of them:

```
val dashBoardItems_data = DashBoardItems()

val data = remember {
    mutableStateOf<DashBoardItems>(DashBoardItems())
}
```

You can call it like `DashBoardItems(0F, 0F, 0F, 0F)` or specify default values in your constructor:

```
data class DashBoardItems(
    val Amaahda: Float = 0F,
    val Expenses: Float = 0F,
    val Lacagta_La_dirayo: Float = 0F,
    val Total: Float = 0F,
)
```

Another problem you will soon encounter is that you can't just call api requests from your composables like that, you will need a `LaunchedEffect` or better a `ViewModel`.

Comment: Mr bina it shows error also

Comment: gson.fromJson(it, DashBoardItems::class.java) {
        dashBoardItems_data.add(it)
}

Comment: I want to solve all errors in my code? anyone here to help me?

Comment: Well what does the error say? What would you expect `dashBoardItems_data.add(it)` to do? I can't see no `add` method on your `DashBoardItems` class. Looking at the gson documentation `gson.fromJson` returns the instance of the class, which means you would need something like `data.value = gson.fromJson(it, DashBoardItems::class.java)`... You apparently don't understand your code at all, where did you get it from?

Comment: Thanks Jan bina, my code is working. But can I remove 0f from all veriables